# How to group opened application windows on macOS

Tags: macos, macbook, macos-highsierra

Im wondering if it is possible to group opened chrome windows in Windows 10 way like this

[image: here]

on macOS High Sierra. Currently i discovered that it is possible by right clicking chrome icon and there it is a list, but i want to do it on graphic way and by click/mouse enter like grouped applications.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any method to gather them in the Dock, but you can use Mission Control to show a quick overview of all open windows & all open Spaces - default gesture is three-finger swipe up the trackpad, but see [Apple KB-Use Mission Control on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT204100) for other methods.

[image]

"Group windows by application" is a Mission Control pref. Unchecked it will just spread out all open window previews to fill the available space.

[image]